# What is the best practice when dealing with different dataset in Redis

Tags: redis

Is it better to use namespaces to separate datasets or create a new database for each purpose?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case, but my rule of thumb is: If you have a very large quantity of related data **keys** that are unrelated to all the rest of your data in Redis, put them in a new database. Reasons being:

1. You may need to (non-ideally) use the `keys` command to get all of that data at some point, and having the data segregated makes that much cheaper.
2. You may want to switch to a second redis server later, and having related data pre-segregated makes this much easier.
3. You can keep your databases named somewhere, so it's easier for you, or a new employee to figure out where to look for particular data.

Conversely, if your data *is* related to other data, they should always live in the same database, so you can easily write pipelines and lua scripts that can access both.