# Using database as a key prefix in redis

Tags: python, redis

I'm evaluating using redis to store some session values. When constructing the redis client ([we will be using this python one](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)) I get to pass in the db to use. Is it appropriate to use the DB as a sort of prefix for my keys? E.g. store all session keys in db 0 and some messages in db 1 and so on? Or should I keep all my applications keys in the same db?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best practice when dealing with different dataset in Redis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654503/what-is-the-best-practice-when-dealing-with-different-dataset-in-redis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654503/what-is-the-best-practice-when-dealing-with-different-dataset-in-redis/18663850#18663850):

> It depends on your use case, but my rule of thumb is: If you have a
>   very large quantity of related data keys that are unrelated to all the
>   rest of your data in Redis, put them in a new database. Reasons being:
>
> You may need to (non-ideally) use the keys command to get all of that
>   data at some point, and having the data segregated makes that much
>   cheaper.
>
> You may want to switch to a second redis server later, and having
>   related data pre-segregated makes this much easier.
>
> You can keep your databases named somewhere, so it's easier for you,
>   or a new employee to figure out where to look for particular data.
>
> Conversely, if your data is related to other data, they should always
>   live in the same database, so you can easily write pipelines and lua
>   scripts that can access both.